# How to make mail command to send email to root after installing msmtp?

Tags: email, mail-command

Install a simple SMTP client:

```
sudo apt install msmtp  msmtp-mda
```

Set in msmtprc
::

```
cat   .msmtprc
account default
host smtp.qq.com
from x1@qq.com
auth on
tls on
tls_certcheck off
user x1@qq.com
password  xxxx
logfile ~/.msmtp.log
```

I can send email with qq account.

```
echo "Testing msmtp " | mail -s "hi root" -r x1@qq.com   -- aa@yahoo.com
```

The email can be found in yahoo email.
I find a new issue that user can't send email to root in system!

```
echo "cron task work done " | mail -s "hi root" root
mail: cannot send message: Process exited with a non-zero status
```

Check the log:

```
Aug 24 20:47:31 host=smtp.qq.com tls=on auth=on user=x1@qq.com from=debian@debian.debian recipients=root@debian.debian smtpstatus=501 smtpmsg='501 Mail from address must be same as authorization user.' errormsg='envelope from address debian@debian.debian not accepted by the server' exitcode=EX_DATAERR

echo "cron task work done " | mail -s "hi root" -r debian@debian.debian  root
```

The log info:

```
Aug 29 06:56:39 host=smtp.qq.com tls=on auth=on user=x1@qq.com from=debian@debian.debian recipients=root@debian.debian smtpstatus=501 smtpmsg='501 Mail from address must be same as authorization user.' errormsg='envelope from address debian@debian.debian not accepted by the server' exitcode=EX_DATAERR
```

Everytime mail command was called ,it relay to external host smtp.qq.com enven if i specify return host as debian@debian.debian,how can make mail command send email between user and root in the system?
I find that postfix or exim4 will be removed when to install msmtp-mda,the fact maybe realted with my issue.

Comment: msmtp is written specially for the purpose of routing **all** your mail to an external "smart host" that sends it further. In short, msmtp == no local mail. If you want to have **both** local mail **and** use an external smart host, you must install a full MTA like Postfix and configure it appropriately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've installed a simple forwarding mail server (`msmtp`). Here is the package description [from Debian](https://packages.debian.org/bookworm/msmtp)

> **Package: msmtp (1.8.23-1)**
>
> *light SMTP client with support for server profiles*
>
> `msmtp` is an SMTP client that can be used to send mails from Mutt and probably other MUAs (mail user agents). It forwards mails to an SMTP server (for example at a free mail provider), which takes care of the final delivery. Using profiles, it can be easily configured to use different SMTP servers with different configurations, which makes it ideal for mobile clients.

The relevant point here is that it, "*forwards mails to an SMTP server […] which takes care of the final delivery*".

What this means that using `msmtp` you can only forward emails to your remote mail server; you cannot deliver locally. If you want to do that install Exim, Postfix, Sendmail, or one of the other full-featured MTAs (mail transport agents).